# How to prevent android device back button from going back to splash screen in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

I have made a logo screen for my app which redirects the user to the appropriate location (home screen if the user is logged in and the welcome/splash screen if he is not). After I reach the home screen I can go back to the previous screen by pressing the back button on the android phone. I want to prevent the user from going back to the logo screen.

**Things I have tried:**

WillPopScope() with onWillPop returning false

**My logo screen code:**

```
class LogoScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LogoScreenState createState() => _LogoScreenState();
}

class _LogoScreenState extends State<LogoScreen> {
  var preferences;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    startTimer();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async => false,
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Image.asset(
                "assets/images/g1177.png",
                scale: 10.0,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  startTimer() {
    var _duration = Duration(milliseconds: 2000);
    return Timer(_duration, navigate);
  }

  navigate() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (preferences.getBool("is_logged_in") == true) {
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
        return HomeScreen();
      }));
    } else {
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
        return SplashScreen();
      }));
    }
  }
}
```

Why this approach doesn't work on my device?

Answer (score 3):

Use `.pushReplacement(...)` instead of `.push(...)`

> pushReplacement Replace the current route of the navigator that most tightly encloses
> the given context by pushing the given route and then disposing the
> previous route once the new route has finished animating in.

Comment: Thanks so much for replying! However, I have found the answer.  I am using will pop screen on the logo screen but if I use it on the home screen itself then it works. So if you apply will pop scope on a screen then you can't pop back from that screen. Thanks!

Comment: But it is not the best solution, because the splash screen will stays at the stack and you can't navigate back to it, so it is better to replace it with the new screen better than push new screen on top of it.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks! Your approach is right, thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. If I apply `WillPopScope()` on the Logo Screen then when I am on the logo screen, if I press the back button then I can't go further back from that screen. Hence, if I use `WillPopScope` on the home screen then I can't use the back button on that screen. Here is my Home Screen build method:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        return false;
      },
      child: Scaffold(

       //add your UI here like your appBar, body, bottomNavBar etc..

      )  //Scaffold

    );  //WillPopScope
```